# MQL5 not taking screenshot while testing

Tags: mql5

I have  tried to modify the script written in MQL4 to MQL5. The output expected was to have the files in the `Files` folder. But there is nothing to be seeing. No error and warning found.
Kindly, suggest me the improvement so I can take the screen shot of the graph while am testing.

Here is the script:

```
#define        WIDTH  800     // Image width to call ChartScreenShot() 
#define        HEIGHT 600     // Image height to call ChartScreenShot() 

//--- input parameters 
input int      pictures=5;    // The number of images in the series 
int            mode=1;       // -1 denotes a shift to the right edge of the chart, 1 - to the left 
int            bars_shift=300;// The number of bars when scrolling the chart using ChartNavigate() 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Expert initialization function                                   | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
void OnInit() 
  { 
//--- Disable chart autoscroll 
   ChartSetInteger(0,CHART_AUTOSCROLL,false); 
//--- Set the shift of the right edge of the chart 
   ChartSetInteger(0,CHART_SHIFT,true); 
//--- Show a candlestick chart 
   ChartSetInteger(0,CHART_MODE,CHART_CANDLES); 
//--- 
   Print("Preparation of the Expert Advisor is completed"); 
  } 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
//| Expert tick function                                             | 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
void OnTick() 
  { 
//--- 
int id = 0;

  Print(__FUNCTION__,TimeCurrent(),"   id=",id,"   mode=",mode); 
//--- Handle the CHARTEVENT_CLICK event ("A mouse click on the chart") 
   if(id==CHARTEVENT_CLICK) 
     { 
      //--- Initial shift from the chart edge 
      int pos=0; 
      //--- Operation with the left chart edge 
      if(mode>0) 
        { 
         //--- Scroll the chart to the left edge 
         ChartNavigate(0,CHART_BEGIN,pos); 
         for(int i=0;i<pictures;i++) 
           { 
            //--- Prepare a text to show on the chart and a file name 
            string name="ChartScreenShot"+"CHART_BEGIN"+string(pos)+".gif"; 
            //--- Show the name on the chart as a comment 
            Comment(name); 
            //--- Save the chart screenshot in a file in the terminal_directory\MQL5\Files\ 
            if(ChartScreenShot(0,name,WIDTH,HEIGHT,ALIGN_LEFT)) 
               Print("We've saved the screenshot ",name); 
            //--- 
            pos+=bars_shift; 
            //--- Give the user time to look at the new part of the chart 
            Sleep(3000); 
            //--- Scroll the chart from the current position bars_shift bars to the right 
            ChartNavigate(0,CHART_CURRENT_POS,bars_shift); 
           } 
         //--- Change the mode to the opposite 
         mode*=-1; 
        } 
      else // Operation with the right chart edge 
        { 
         //--- Scroll the chart to the right edge 
         ChartNavigate(0,CHART_END,pos); 
         for(int i=0;i<pictures;i++) 
           { 
            //--- Prepare a text to show on the chart and a file name 
            string name="ChartScreenShot"+"CHART_END"+string(pos)+".gif"; 
            //--- Show the name on the chart as a comment 
            Comment(name); 
            //--- Save the chart screenshot in a file in the terminal_directory\MQL5\Files\ 
            if(ChartScreenShot(0,name,WIDTH,HEIGHT,ALIGN_RIGHT)) 
               Print("We've saved the screenshot ",name); 
            //--- 
            pos+=bars_shift; 
            //--- Give the user time to look at the new part of the chart 
            Sleep(3000); 
            //--- Scroll the chart from the current position bars_shift bars to the right 
            ChartNavigate(0,CHART_CURRENT_POS,-bars_shift); 
           } 
         //--- Change the mode to the opposite 
         mode*=1; 
        } 
     } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object events must be handled inside OnChartEvent() not OnTick() function.
In testing OnChartEvent doesnt work - it is not supported

Comment: I want to take snapshot of every tick. Hence, I have placed the code in the `OnTick()`.

Can you help me get the snapshot of every tick?

Comment: what is id in your case and why do you think the condition (id==CHARTEVENT_CLICK) holds? and second: if you save screenshots every tick, you must have a unique name for each tick, otherwise a new file is to the replace the old one with the same name

Comment: ok... Is that the mistake I am making? I guess the CHARTEVENT_CLICK should be replaced with something else relevant in my case. I will let you know if it helps.

Comment: CHARTEVENT_CLICK is usually applied when you have a button and OnChartEvent() function added into the code - in such case each event (mouse move is turned on, object clicked, moved, edited etc) is reported to the expert advisor if the chart matches. you may remove id completely to create a chart and keep in mind that each tick your chart would be moved using your ChartNavigate function